# Making bind to listen to localhost in netns

Tags: debian, networking, bind

I have a Debian Jessie running Bind. There is an OpenVPN connection set up. And `resolv.conf` set up to use local Bind first:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

I want to set up system in a way that *certain* programs access internet *only* through that VPN connection (in the absence of that connection it must not have any access anywhere), and the rest to access internet directly. I want *all* programs to use local Bind to resolve domain names and remove that `4.2.2.4` from `resolv.conf`.

I thought that network namespaces are suitable tool for a job: I move VPN interface into network namespace (so it is the only connection available there except loopback), then run those *certain* programs in my network namespace. I made following script that I set up to run as OpenVPN `route-up` script:

```
NS=zzz

if [ ! -f /var/run/netns/$NS ]; then
        /sbin/ip netns add $NS
fi

/sbin/ip link set $dev netns $NS
/sbin/ip netns exec $NS /sbin/ifconfig lo up
/sbin/ip netns exec $NS /sbin/ifconfig $dev $ifconfig_local pointopoint $ifconfig_remote up
/sbin/ip netns exec $NS /sbin/route add default gw $ifconfig_remote metric 1024
```

Works fine for me, except that Bind does not listen for loopback interface in my network namespace, so all name resolution requests go to external DNS. How do I fix that? Can I specify somehow that both loopback (regular one and netns one) are the same? Or should I run another copy of Bind in my namespace? Something else?